# The first cell of UITableView is blank (TableView in UIView)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, custom-cell

I have the following code to create my cells in a UITableView.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 5;
}

 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{    
     NSString *CellIdentifier = @"futureAppointments";
     FutureAppointmentsViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (nil == cell) {
        [tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"FutureAppointmentsViewCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        cell = [[FutureAppointmentsViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                  reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
   }

   NSUInteger position = indexPath.row;
   cell.appointmentDescription.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu. %@. %@", (unsigned long)position, @"Steve", @"10/03/"];

   return cell;
}
```

The problems is, the first cell of the tableView is missing. It should start with **0. Steve** but instead starts with **1. Steve**. Also there are only 4 elements in the list instead of 5.

[image]

When I place a break point in the code, the first cell is nil.

Does anyone know what might be happening?

Comment: maybe your _header_ view covers it? have your tried to pull down the tableview to see whether the cell is under _something_, maybe?

Answer (score 3):

**Put this line of code:**

```
 [tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"FutureAppointmentsViewCell" 
                                       bundle:nil] 
 forCellReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
```

In `viewDidLoad`. It doesn't belong in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. Once you do this then you no longer need to check whether the cell is nil.

**Change cellForRowAtIndexPath:**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{    
     NSString *CellIdentifier = @"futureAppointments";
     FutureAppointmentsViewCell *cell = 
      [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];


   NSUInteger position = indexPath.row;
   cell.appointmentDescription.text = 
    [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu. %@. %@", 
     (unsigned long)position, @"Steve", @"10/03/"];

   return cell;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention in my question that the code I am working on has been done with views and so I don't have a viewDidLoadMethod to work with.

Comment: Then put it in init method of the view. Move it out of cellForRowAtIndexPath. And BTW you realy should use ViewControllers.

Comment: I wil give that a try. I have inherited this code base so don't have a choice. You don't need to convince me to use View Controllers :-).

Answer (score 1):

I think I had similar problem when I was using `UITableView` inside `UIView` and initialized it in init method.

I was not able to find good explanation for that behavior, but I've found tricky solution for that - I was reloading `UITableView` instance from `UIViewController` in `viewDidAppear` method.

I would also like to know, why `UITableView` is not drawing all `UITableViewCell`.